# Check if objects within a variable are also contained in another variable (jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables

I hope the title somewhat sums up what I am trying to achieve.

Let's say I have two variables:

```
var one = $('div.foo, div.faa, div.fee, span, a, .all-sorts-of-objects'),
    two = $('div.fii, div.foo, span, .all-sorts-of-objects-two');
```

And now, I want to check if objects contained within **two** are also contained within **one**. In other words, if there are any objects within both variables.

I need this so that I can set-up a non-overriding hover function (i.e. because I'm adding inline color-styles, I need to target my objects wisely). This is the logic I came up with: (note the *if(one == two)* which is essentially my question).

```
one.hover(function() {
    if(one == two) { // if there is one or more objects in both variables..
       $(this).css('color', 'red');
    } else {
       $(this).css('color', 'blue');
    } 
}, function() {
    // ...
});
```

I hope I have been clear enough. If not, please let me know and I will do my best to explain this better.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a quick and dirty way to do it:

```
var one = $('div.foo, div.faa, div.fee, span, a, .all-sorts-of-objects').addClass('one');
var two = $('div.fii, div.foo, span, .all-sorts-of-objects-two').addClass('two');

one.hover(function() {
    if(one.hasClass('two')) {
       $(this.css('color', 'red');
    }
});
```

Comment: Hey, thanks a ton! In the end I took a different but similar path. Your idea got me started. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In my book the cleanest way (apart from refactoring to avoid these duplicate selectors if possible) would be to use the [merge](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.merge/) and [unique](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.unique/) jQuery utilities, something like:

```
var $merged = $.merge(one, two);
var $unique = $.unique($merged.get());
```

The $unique now has the unique, or, if you like, distinct elements.

Comment: I would have gone this way, if (for whatever possible reason) the $unique object would have held all my elements without breaking/splitting them. Somehow, $unique echoed parts of my elements only, such as "div#era-blocks-container" and nothing else. Either way, thanks for this!